# Integration over ideles over $\Bbb{Q}$ , Tate`s thesis special case

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, harmonic-analysis, adeles

Let $f\in S(A_\Bbb{Q})$ that is $f$ is **adelic** Schwartz-Bruhat function over $\Bbb{Q}$, such that all its components in the finite places  are characteristic functions of the corresponding ring of integers and the infinite component is denoted by $h$. 
$A_\Bbb{Q}$ is the adele of $\Bbb{Q}$

Let $Z(f,s)=\int_If(x)|x|^sd^{*}x$ where $I$ is the idele group of $\Bbb{Q}$.
How to show that for $\sigma \in (0,1) $ where $\sigma$=Real($s$)

(for all $h$ which is a Schwartz function over $\Bbb{R}$, $Z(f,s)=0$) iff $\zeta_\Bbb{Q}(s)=0$.

Moreover how to show that

$Z_+(f,s)[=$ by definition $\int_{|x|>1}f(x)|x|^sd^{*}x$)]$=\int_{\Bbb{R}}h(x)(|x|^{s-1}\sum_{0<n<|x|+1}n^{-s})dx$

I tried by decomposing $Z(f,s)$ into local components but nothing worked out.  I am just learning Tate`s thesis from the book Ramakrishnan Valenza.

I am not completely expert in handling integration over ideles.
The exercise is [here.](http://www.math.u-psud.fr/~ratazzi/montd10_11.pdf)
 Please help...

Comment: You have a misplaced parenthesis in paragraph 2 line 3.